# Glassfish and log4j

Tags: java, servlets, glassfish

I am trying to deploy 2 servlets in glassfish with log4j library.

I have no problems in tomcat. Each servlet writes in its own file but in tomcat, I found this guide https://blogs.oracle.com/naman/entry/configure_log4j_for_use_in to configure and support log4f library.

I got the first servlet working with it. And it writes logs in its log file. But whenever I deploy the secod servlet, I don't see its logs. The first one keeps writing in its own file but the second one not.

I modify the logback.xml file included in config folder to include both files and all packages but it seems to ignore it. This is my logback.xml file:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

        <configuration>

          <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
            <!-- encoders are assigned the type
                 ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
            <encoder>
              <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </encoder>
          </appender>

          <logger name="com.lordofthejars.foo" level="INFO" additivity="false">
           <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
          </logger>


          <appender name="SERVER-FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
                <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                    <!-- daily rollover -->0
                    <fileNamePattern>/root/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/serverregister-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>

                    <!-- keep 7 days' worth of history -->
                    <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
                    <TimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                        <MaxFileSize>512MB</MaxFileSize>
                    </TimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
                </rollingPolicy>
                <append>true</append>
                <encoder>
                    <pattern>%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%p]  %logger{5}:%L - %msg%n</pattern>
                </encoder>
            </appender>

             <appender name="REGMAN-FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
                <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                    <!-- daily rollover -->
                    <!--<fileNamePattern>${catalina.home}/logs/registermanager-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>-->
                    <fileNamePattern>/root/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/registermanager-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
                    <!-- keep 7 days' worth of history -->
                    <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
                    <TimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                        <MaxFileSize>512MB</MaxFileSize>
                    </TimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
                </rollingPolicy>
                <append>true</append>
                <encoder>
                    <pattern>%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%p]  %logger{5}:%L - %msg%n</pattern>
                </encoder>
            </appender>


          <logger name="com.eu.iotapi.handlers.AuthenticationGatewayHandler" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
                <appender-ref ref="SERVER-FILE"/>
          </logger>
          <logger name="com.eu.iotapi.handlers.AuthenticationHandler" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
                <appender-ref ref="SERVER-FILE"/>
          </logger>
          <logger name="com.eu.iotapi.handlers.DeviceValidationHandler" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
                <appender-ref ref="SERVER-FILE"/>
          </logger>
          <logger name="com.eu.iotapi.handlers.EventValidationHandler" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
                <appender-ref ref="SERVER-FILE"/>
          </logger>
          <logger name="com.eu.iotapi.handlers.GatewayValidationHandler" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
                <appender-ref ref="SERVER-FILE"/>
          </logger>
          <logger name="com.eu.iotapi.handlers.ObservationValidationHandler" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
                <appender-ref ref="SERVER-FILE"/>
          </logger>
          <logger name="com.eu.iotapi.resources.PublicationsResource" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
                <appender-ref ref="SERVER-FILE"/>
          </logger>
          <logger name="com.eu.iotapi.resources.RegisterDeviceOnBackground" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
                <appender-ref ref="SERVER-FILE"/>
          </logger>
          <logger name="com.eu.iotapi.resources.RegisterGatewayOnBackground" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
                <appender-ref ref="SERVER-FILE"/>
          </logger>
          <logger name="com.eu.iotapi.resources.RegistrationResource" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
                <appender-ref ref="SERVER-FILE"/>
          </logger>
          <logger name="com.eu.iotapi.resources.SubmitEventOnBackground" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
                <appender-ref ref="SERVER-FILE"/>
          </logger>
          <logger name="com.eu.iotapi.resources.SubmitObservationOnBackground" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
                <appender-ref ref="SERVER-FILE"/>
          </logger>
          <logger name="com.eu.iotapi.uns.device.RegisterDeviceHandler" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
                <appender-ref ref="SERVER-FILE"/>
          </logger>
          <logger name="com.eu.iotapi.uns.events.SubmitEventsHandler" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
                <appender-ref ref="SERVER-FILE"/>
          </logger>
          <logger name="com.eu.iotapi.uns.device.RegisterGatewayHandler" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
                <appender-ref ref="SERVER-FILE"/>
          </logger>
          <logger name="com.eu.iotapi.uns.observations.SubmitObservationsHandler" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
                <appender-ref ref="SERVER-FILE"/>
          </logger>
          <logger name="com.eu.iotapi.resources.DeviceTranslator" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
                <appender-ref ref="SERVER-FILE"/>
          </logger>


          <logger name="com.eu.registermanager.eventbroker.device.registration.DeviceRegistrationHandler" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
                <appender-ref ref="REGMAN-FILE"/>
          </logger>
          <logger name="com.eu.registermanager.eventbroker.gateway.GatewayRegistrationHandler" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
                <appender-ref ref="REGMAN-FILE"/>
          </logger>
          <logger name="com.eu.registermanager.handlers.AuthenticationGatewayHandler" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
                <appender-ref ref="REGMAN-FILE"/>
          </logger>
          <logger name="com.eu.registermanager.handlers.AuthenticationHandler" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
                <appender-ref ref="REGMAN-FILE"/>
          </logger>
          <logger name="com.eu.registermanager.resources.RegisterDeviceOnEventBrokerOnBackground" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
                <appender-ref ref="REGMAN-FILE"/>
          </logger>
          <logger name="com.eu.registermanager.resources.RegisterGatewayOnEventBrokerOnBackground" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
                <appender-ref ref="REGMAN-FILE"/>
          </logger>
          <logger name="com.eu.registermanager.resources.RegisterResource" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
                <appender-ref ref="REGMAN-FILE"/>
          </logger>

          <root level="INFO">          
            <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
          </root>  

        </configuration>
```

Comment: I guess you mean `log4j` but you are showing a configuration file for `logback`...

Comment: Yes, sorry. log4j. I don't know if they are differents libraries or not. I got the projects from other work mate. Maybe it is problem f logback but I just have the name of the file in logback.xml and it is taking it from there. But just from one servlet and not from both.